# How your codes affect your data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am working one of the data with Python functions. I am cleaning data reassign values delete columns and create new columns. All my codes are working well and  I can see my results on the Jupyter Notebook but actually I want to my code changes my original data that I can see what is happening in the file(.csv).

How can I create my functions?

I opened .csv file

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", na_values=['?', '$', 'None', 'Wrong Answer'])
```

and create functions(e.g.);

```
def chars(x):
    return x.replace(x[:2], '')

data[['trialcol']] = data[['trialcol']].applymap(chars)
```

this two codes just example for showing my codes.

Comment: you need to save your dataframe, like to_csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the original `.csv` file, `to_csv` is what you want. Documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Try:

```
data.to_csv('data_modified.csv', index=False)
```